# iOS Subscription Plan Options Don't Show for Specific Users

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm running into a support issue with my iOS app. Certain users are trying to subscribe via an In App Purchase, but the plan options for the subscription are not showing up for them so they are unable to subscribe.

I've tested this with the following:

- Apple User without a payment method setup
- Apple User with a PayPal account set for the payment method.
- Apple user with a credit card setup.

The subscription plans still show up for all these configurations.

Once again this seems to only be happening for a specific set of users.

Answer (score 0):

James there's not a lot to go on here. As a developer you are responsible for displaying/merchandising the subscription. There's no way to be helped until you can provide more information.

Comment: As stated in my initial question I am able to successfully display the plans.  We have thousands of subscribers that HAVEN'T had a problem with this implementation. I was hoping someone would have some insight into something that Apple might being doing to block this request.

Comment: Apple do not block these requests. IAP's are global, there are no restrictions in fetching the product information. This could be adverse network performance, but also perhaps unlikely. You've listed various payment methods above, even if a user had no payment methods available, or even signed into the the App Store, you will be able to get a response from the request.